# Python: match a long string with special characters and white spaces and then prepend two characters to the beginning

Tags: python, regex, special-characters, string-matching, prepend

I'm not sure how to approach this, i'm trying to match this long string in a text file that has lots of whitespace and special characters and append the characters to the front ie. "//"

i need to match this line:

```
$menu_items['gojo_project']                    => array('http://www.gojo.net/community/plugin-inventory/ops-gojo/gojo', 'gojo',3),
```

and turn it into this:

```
//$menu_items['gojo_project']                    => array('http://www.gojo.net/community/plugin-inventory/ops-gojo/gojo', 'gojo',3),
```

notice i just prepended two '/' character.

I tried using re.escape to format the string, but its just really long and still throw sytax error.  Am i going about this the right way using 're' ?  or is there a better pythonic way to match a string like this one in a text file and prepend to it?

Edit: Forgot to mention that i need to edit the file in-line.  In short, its a long php script that i'm trying to find that line and comment it out (ie. //).  So, I cant really use some of the proposed solutions(i think) since they have it writing the modification to a separate file.

Comment: If it just this **exact** string you can do `str.replace('your_string', '// your_string')`

Comment: It looks like you're parsing php. Is that right? Regex are probably not the right answer here.

Comment: @Daenyth : Yes, that is correct. It is a PHP script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `fileinput` it will let you read over a file and rewrite lines in place:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input("myfile.txt", inplace = 1):
    if line == "$menu_items['gojo_project']                    => array('http://www.gojo.net/community/plugin-inventory/ops-gojo/gojo', 'gojo',3),":
        line = '//' + line
    print line,
```

Comment: Strange, when i run this , the file becomes empty, ie. Null

Comment: My apologies, inplace = 1, not True. Give it a go now.

Comment: Thanks Peter, this worked.  I changed it slighty to match on "contains" since I could not get exact match working. I.e. if "SOME STRING" in line:

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to match exactly that string, it would be easier just to use the string equality operator, rather than regular expressions.

```
longString = "$menu_items['gojo_project']                    => array('http://www.gojo.net/community/plugin-inventory/ops-gojo/gojo', 'gojo',3),"

input = open("myTextFile.txt", "r")
output = open("myOutput.txt", "w")
for line in input:
    if line.rstrip() == longString: #rstrip removes the trailing newline/carriage return
        line = "//" + line
    output.write(line)
input.close()
output.close()
```